# How can I print a xhtml page opened in a tab with JSF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have three commandlink: the first one open a xhtml page in another tab, the second cancels the operation and the third one saves it (a Cancel and a Save button)

If I put the following script in the xhtml page the Cancel and Save buttons don't work until I print the page or click cancel.

```
<script>
  $window.load(function(){
    window.print();
});
</script>
```

I want the other buttons to work regardless of what I do with the page opened in another tab. How can I got about it?

Comment: Well the dialog appears and locks up the browser....

Comment: This might simply be because the print dialog is 'blocking'? This is al client side and does not seem jsf related

Comment: @epascarello The thing is, If I don't write the script to open the print dialog when the page loads but press "Ctrl+P" after I got the xhtml in another tab, the Cancel and Save button work as expected. I'd want to achieve that kind of scenario but having the print dialog opened with the script

Comment: There might be a difference, and it might even differ per browser, but it is **not**  PrimeFaces, JSF(-2) or javascript related. It **might** be jquery related if the `$window.load()` is blocking

Comment: From the JQuery docs, The [`$window.load(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is not the right one to use anymore for what you want. You should use the [`$document.ready(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). It might be that this is the cause of the problem you encounter

Comment: @Kukeltje It's the same with $document.ready 

I forgot to mention I'm testing in Chrome. I'm now starting to believe that's the expected behavior: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437230

Comment: So it is a plain html issue? Not jquery, jsf or PrimeFaces related